# C# group by Datatable and write the items per each group to a text file

Tags: c#, datatable, group-by, text-files

I have a datatable with two columns, one column is name an other column is group

example-

```
Name     Group
John     HR,Finance
Tom      HR,
Jonna    Finance,
Adam     IT,
Rachael  Default,IT,
```

I want to group the above data by their group name and then write it to a text file as follow

```
Start - HR
John
Tom
End

Start - Finance
John
Jonna
End

Start - IT
Adam 
Rachael  
End

Start - Default
Rachael
End
```

This is how I grouped but not able to think how to get around the multiple groups separated by the comma and then use that information to write to the text file as above

```
  var result = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<string>("GroupName") into grp
                select grp.ToList();
```

Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// sample data
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("John", "HR,Finance");
table.Rows.Add("Tom", "HR,");
table.Rows.Add("Jonna", "Finance,");
table.Rows.Add("Adam", "IT,");
table.Rows.Add("Rachael", "Default,IT,");

// get a distinct list of all the departments
var departments = table.AsEnumerable()
                       .SelectMany(r => r.Field<string>("Group").Split(new[] { ',' },
                                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                       .Distinct();

// loop through each department
foreach (string department in departments)
{

    // get any employees that are apart of the current department
    var employees = table.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Group").Contains(department));

    // write output according to OP's format
    Console.WriteLine("Start - {0}", department);

    foreach (var employee in employees)
        Console.WriteLine(employee.Field<string>("Name"));

    Console.WriteLine("End");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Start - HR
John
Tom
End

Start - Finance
John
Jonna
End

Start - IT
Adam
Rachael
End

Start - Default
Rachael
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(row => row.Field<string>("Group").Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
        (row, group) => new { group, row })
    .GroupBy(item => item.group);
```

Sample usage

```
TextWriter writer = Console.Out; // File.CreateText(@"...");
foreach (var group in result)
{
    writer.WriteLine("Start - " + group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
        writer.WriteLine(item.row.Field<string>("Name"));
    writer.WriteLine("End");
    writer.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I wish I could accept more than one answer